# Trying to parse JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm a complete beginner at node.js and trying to figure out how to send the contents of a JSON-object using REST. My code only results in an error saying "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ﻿ in JSON at position 0". I have used an online validator to see that the JSON is corrent. What is the issue?

```
// GET courses
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/api/courses', function(req, res) {
  var rawdata = fs.readFileSync('miun-db.json');
  var data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
  res.send(data.courses);
});
```

Comment: you'll need to check and see what rawdata contains and then post the value of that before anybody can help you.  Although, once you see what it actually contains, the problem might become clear.

Comment: Can yu add a fragment of the file here?

Comment: ```{
  "myCourses":[
     {
        "courseCode":"DT158G",
        "status":1
     },
     {
        "courseCode":"DT013G",
        "status":1
     },
     {
        "courseCode":"DT151G",
        "status":1
     },
     {
        "courseCode":"DT018G",
        "status":1
     },
     ```

Comment: Is that from the _file_ or did you inspect the value of `rawdata` itself?  If I remove the last comma and add [} to close the braces, then it parses fine.

Answer (score -1):

The data inside of your file is not formatted properly. Verify that `miun-db.json` is properly formatted before attempting to parse.

Comment: I've validated it with several online validators and auto formatters.

Comment: @FabianTjernström Try this link https://jsonlint.com/ and let us know if there's any issues with that file

Comment: says it's valid.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that your file is not properly formatted, check this out [Working with JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON).

Also you can just import the JSON file and use it without `fs`.

```
import miunDb from './miun-db.json';

app.get('/api/courses', function(req, res) {
  res.send(miunDb.courses);
});
```

Comment: It's not able to reach the URL for some reason.

Comment: The file should be in the same folder or try to give it a proper path and if you are not using ES6 or above try using require to import the file.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [fs.readFileSync docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) you can pass options to the function.

```
fs.readFileSync(path[, options])
```

> If the encoding option is specified then this function returns a string. Otherwise it returns a buffer.

Since you don't pass any options you get a buffer and not the string content of the file.

Either you pass encoding to the function, e.g.

```js
var rawdata = fs.readFileSync('miun-db.json', {encoding:'utf8'});
var data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
```

or you convert  the  buffer to string. E.g.

```
var rawdata = fs.readFileSync('miun-db.json');
var data = JSON.parse(rawdata.toString('utf8'));
```

---

*Edit:*

Your error message says you have an invalid character which is non printable. Seems like your file starts with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (zero width no-break space (ZWNBSP)).

What happens if you try to remove it?

```js
function stripBOM(content) {
  content = content.toString()
  // Remove byte order marker. This catches EF BB BF (the UTF-8 BOM)
  // because the buffer-to-string conversion in `fs.readFileSync()`
  // translates it to FEFF, the UTF-16 BOM.
  if (content.charCodeAt(0) === 0xFEFF) {
    content = content.slice(1)
  }
  return content
}

// [...]

var rawdata = fs.readFileSync('miun-db.json', {encoding:'utf8'});
var data = JSON.parse(stripBOM(rawdata));

// [...]
```

Credit goes to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pbakondy/f5045eff725193dad9c7).

Comment: I tried it both ways. Same issue.

Comment: @FabianTjernström I updated my answer. Can you try this approach with removing BOM?